# Doubly Linked List Pointer Confusion

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Below is the code for inserting a node in a doubly linked list.

```
struct dllist
{
    int data;
    struct dllist *prev, *next;
};


void DLLInsert(struct dllist **head, int position, int data)
{
    int k = 1;
    struct dllist *temp, *newNode;
    newNode = (struct dllist *)malloc(sizeof(struct dllist));
    if (!newNode)
    {
        printf("Memory Error\n");
    }
    newNode->data = data;
    if (position == 1)
    {
        newNode->next = *head;
        newNode->prev = NULL;
        *head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = *head;
        while (temp->next != NULL && k < position - 1)
        {
            k++;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if (temp->next == NULL)
        {
            temp->next = newNode;
            newNode->prev = temp;
            newNode->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            newNode->prev = temp;
            newNode->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = newNode;
            temp->next->prev = newNode;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting somewhat confused in the underlying pointer operations being a newbie. A **head is passed onto the function to modify it. But in case when the position>1, a copy of *head(temp) is used to modify the list compared to the case when position==1. Can anybody explain me why is it so?

Thanks

Comment: In one case, you only need to modify what's being pointed to by `*head`.  In the other, you need to modify the pointer itself.  (Draw the two cases out on paper with boxes and arrows, and you'll see why.)

Answer (score 1):

When position > 1, temp is set to `*head`, and the code iterates `temp` through the linked list to the node at index `position`. Effectively, you are modifying the node at index `position`.

When position = 1, you are modifying the head node, so you don't need to iterate.

Comment: @irrelephant-Thanks for the explanation. So in effect it means that I can modify the struct elements(namely data,next and prev) by passing *head to a function, but to modify *head itself, I need to pass **head. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how that has to do with this question about linked lists. To use `DLLInsert()` you would always pass a `struct dlllist **` as `head`.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `position==1`, your new element will become the new head. You already know exactly where it is. Otherwise, you need to find the position.

```
temp = *head;
        while (temp->next != NULL && k < position - 1)
```

This is used to iterate through the list until you find the element in the position you are going to insert at.

```
    temp = temp->next;
```

The first element you assign to `temp` is `head`, but it is replaced with the next element in each iteration.